# SCOPE_IDENTITY when inserting values

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, nhibernate, orm

I got this error message when trying to execute my ORM program.

> NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: 'could not insert:
>   [NHibernateWinFormsApp.Employee][SQL: INSERT INTO Employee DEFAULT
>   VALUES; select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]'

This is my mapping file **EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="NHibernateWinFormsApp"
                   namespace="NHibernateWinFormsApp">

  <class name="Employee">
    <id name="EmployeeId" column="EmployeeId">
      <column name="EmployeeId" not-null="true" />
      <column name="FirstName" />
      <column name="LastName" />
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <bag name="Department" table="EmployeeDepartment" >
      <key column="EmployeeId" not-null="true" />
      <many-to-many class="Department" column="DepartmentId"/>
    </bag>
  </class>

  <class name="Department">
    <id name="DepartmentId">
      <column name="DepartmentId" not-null="true" />
      <column name="DepartmentName" />
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <bag name="Employee" table="EmployeeDepartment" inverse="true">
      <key column="DepartmentId" not-null="true"/>
      <many-to-many class="Employee" column="EmployeeId"/>
    </bag>
    <property name="DepartmentName" type="string"/>
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

And, into my session:

```
DepartmentRepository departmentRepository = new DepartmentRepository(session);

// get department by id
Department department = departmentRepository.GetById(int.Parse(textDepartment.Text));
employeeData.Department = new List<Department>();
employeeData.Department.Add(department);
department.Employee.Add(employeeData);
```

Does anyone know how to solve this small problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [could not insert select SCOPE\_IDENTITY() fluent nhibernate one to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096975/could-not-insert-select-scope-identity-fluent-nhibernate-one-to-many)

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader I am not sure if I could agree. Please, tell me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: Is this the complete error message? To me, it looks truncated. SQL-Server should tell more. Inspect inner exceptions, seek `SqlException` and consult their `Errors` properties. Otherwise capture the failing insert SQL and replay it directly on your db.

Comment: @Frédéric `Message=could not insert: [NHibernateWinFormsApp.Employee][SQL: INSERT INTO Employee DEFAULT VALUES; select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]`

Comment: @Frédéric `SqlException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'Code'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Employee'. The duplicate key value is (<NULL>, <NULL>).`

Comment: Well, THERE'S your problem. Nothing to do with the Scope_Identity() You're dealing with duplicate values. Check your data to make sure you're not inserting data that already exists (e.g. you already have Null values or is your object not configured correctly?)

Comment: That's it! And, yes, it says "department was null". However I put `departmentRepository.GetById(int.Parse(textDepartment.Text))`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not mapped some columns which must have different values between two records. So they are always inserted with `null`, but you can only have one such employee, causing all other inserts to fail.

Either remove that constraint, or relax it (by replacing it with a filtered unique index ignoring `null` values), or map those columns to some properties and give them unique values for each employee.

But well, bottom line of your trouble is: always consult all `InnerException` and their specific properties if any. That is not a NHibernate specific advice, you should do that with all exceptions you encounter.

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is in the mapping file. I will look for it, and brb. Thank you, @Frédéric.

Comment: Hello, @Frédéric. I changed the mapping file (please, see my EDIT above). I got this message `Foreign key (FKCE90096CDE039EE9:EmployeeDepartment [DepartmentId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (Department [DepartmentId, DepartmentName])`. I am not sure if i understand well the principle of many-to-many mapping. Excuse my ignorance :)

Comment: @user7879148 Do not transform a question into another. Ask a new one.